# Android HTC Sensation resolution QHD

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen-resolution

Any idea how to simulate qHD screen on android emulator. I tried to manually set the resolution, but the phone view is different from simulator view.

My application on phone is truncated, but not in emulator.

Thanks,
M.

Comment: How did you set the hw.lcd.density?

Comment: I tried 160 and 240...but nothing. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `<uses-sdk.../>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to the following:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

just on this, seems this also works within the AndroidManifest.xml: `<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" 
android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" />`

Answer (score 0):

commented from above:

**Try hw.lcd.density 220 – BrainCrash Jul 28 at 13:03**

seems to work :)
thanks!